# Invalid Object Name error in Parse JavaScript SDK

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I am using Parse as a service for my app, specifically the JavaScript SDK.

In my app I have a class that represents a user post in my app containing images and text.

For some reason occasionally when a new object is created by the user, the objectId assigned by parse sometimes causes errors with that particular post.

I get this in the console:

```
t.Error {code: 105, message: "invalid field name: 3qUHMBPCBs"}
```

the field name is the objectId assigned automatically by Parse when the user uploads their post.

Second time this has happened. I noticed when I removed that post, the error disappeared but, obviously I can't keep deferring to that method.

*Updated, code used for the user post below*

so, essentially theres functionality that allows a user to post an update to parse. When the user submits, this function is performed and an object is generated by Parse.

```
    var sendThis = $('#resultImage').attr('src');
    var parseFile = new Parse.File("mypic.jpg", {
        base64: sendThis
    });

    var val = document.getElementById('statusupdateform').value;
    var statusupdate = $('#statusupdateform').val();
    var currentUser = Parse.User.current();
    parseFile.save().then(function() {
        var nameCurrent = currentUser.getUsername();
        var cigarWall = new Parse.Object("cigarwall");
        cigarWall.set("appuser", nameCurrent);
        cigarWall.set("statusupdate", statusupdate);
        cigarWall.set("imagefile", parseFile);
        cigarWall.save({
            success: function() {
                $('#uploadBtn').removeClass('tapActive');

                var postupdate = cigarWall.get('statusupdate');
                //$('#fileselect').attr('data-change', 'false');
                $('#statusInnerWrapper').removeClass('slideLeft');
                location.reload();
            },
            error: function() {
                alert("upload failed. please try again!");
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Please post your code for adding an object. Looking around, it seems that field names [must start with a-z](https://parse.com/docs/android/api/com/parse/ParseException.html#INVALID_KEY_NAME), so I do not think the Parse SDK would generate an invalid key, therefore the bug would be in your code.

Comment: Sure thing. Yeh it seems most of the objects generated by Parse begin with a letter, however there are some objects that begin with the number 4 or 5.

Comment: Thanks - do you also have a stack trace or similar to indicate which line of the code above is causing a problem? BTW, is this code on Parse's servers, or on your own?

Comment: This code is on my own. Negative on the stack trace.

Comment: Hi there.  So I was able to get a trace of where the bug is being initiated I think.  Looks like its this line:  parse-1.2.19.min.js:1184

Comment: Well, finally found the bug, I was accidentally querying for an object ID when I didn't have to. Error gone, app working.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I Had a bad line of code in my Query function for one of the Parse classes. I Was unnecessarily querying against the objectId column.